# Is there a way in AWS CDK to associate a CodeBuild project with a VPC, subnet and security group?

Tags: aws-cdk

I have written a CDK script (typescript) to create a AWS CodeBuild project.  However the build needs to access the internet so needs explicit VPC, security group and subnets set.  I cannot see a way to do this.  I notice that I can associate VPC, subnet and securitygroup with CodeBuild project after creation using aws cli but this is not ideal.  Has anyone found a way to do this directly in CDK?
using CDK version 0.26.0

Comment: Always reduce the question to pieces with attaching code if possible

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share your code when asking a question, it helps others more effectively understand the issue and assist you.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out how to do this.  Below is the code where project is the CodeBuild project object.

```
// associate the VPC, securitygroup and subnets with the codebuild
const projectVpc = project.node.findChild('Resource')  as codebuild.CfnProject;

projectVpc.propertyOverrides.vpcConfig = {
      vpcId: "vpc-xxxxxx",
      securityGroupIds: ["sg-xxxxxx],
      subnets: ["subnet-xxxxx1","subnet-xxxxx2"]
}
```